# Vector of vectors (char): core dumped

Tags: c++, vector, g++

This may be a stupid question, but I simply can't work out why this throws a segmentation fault(core dumped):

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
vector< vector<char> > samplevct;
int main(void)
{
    samplevct[0].push_back('a');
    return 0;
}
```

Might someone explain why this doesn't work?

I use g++, Fedora 20, if this is an information of importance.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a reason not to use a `vector<string>`?

Comment: Probably not at all. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your vector is empty, so you just cannot access `samplevct[0]`. You need to populete the vector with at least one element. For example,

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    using std::vector;
    vector< vector<char> > samplevct(1); // size 1 vector
    samplevct[0].push_back('a');         // OK
    return 0;
}
```

See [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for more on how to use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

It's an empty vector, so `samplevct[0]` doesn't exist. Modifying it is undefined behaviour - and luckily in your case it crashes in an obvious way.